# Find the minimum for the sum of norm and linear function

Tags: inequality, optimization

My problem is:
\begin{equation}
\min_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}_+^3} \quad \|\mathbf{x}\|_p + a^T \mathbf{x} \\
\textrm{subject to} \quad \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{1}{x_i} \leq 1
\end{equation}
where $\|\cdot\|_p$ denotes $L_p$-norm, $p \in \mathbb{N}$, and $\mathbf{a}=[1, 4, 9]^T$.

I can minimize the term $\|\mathbf{x}\|_p$ and $a^T \mathbf{x}$ separately, but the equalities do not hold simultaneously. If considering two terms at the same time, I cannot deal with the term $\|\mathbf{x}\|_p = (\sum_{i=1}^3 |x_i|^p)^{1/p}$ via Cauchy–Schwarz inequality due to the power $\frac{1}{p}$.

Maybe we can turn the inequality constraint into equality constraint by simple arguments and then use Lagrange multiplier, but does anyone have elementary approach to solving this problem or just give me some hints?

Thanks!

Comment: Your objective function and the positivity constraint are convex, which means that if you just had to solve that problem (without the reciprocal constraint), it would be "easy" to solve numerically with a proximal method. However, constraint involving reciprocals is quite nonconvex, which means that a proximal method would probably fail here.

Comment: @Zim the reciprocal constraint is convex as well since $x_i > 0$. The only concern is $p=1$, but the problem is easy for $p>1$.

Comment: Oh right! haha whoops. Well in that case it shouldn't be a problem, right? The nonsmoothness of the $p=1$ stuff can be handled quite easily using a proximal method. The proximity operator of each of your terms is known in the literature, so you can apply a splitting method (e.g. Douglas Rachford in a product space) to solve it. check out http://proximity-operator.net/index.html

Comment: OK. I see. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Yanni99 sure thing, good luck. If you haven't used a proximal method before it may take a bit of time and literature searching. Feel free to ask if you've got questions in that process.